# How to version Pipelines in BizTalk Application?

Tags: version-control, biztalk, versioning, pipeline

!!This is not about custom pipeline!!

I want to know how I can manually specify version for the pipelines that we define using the already provided pipeline components in visual studio?. I am new to BizTalk, and even don't know if we can manually specify version for the pipelines or not. We can specify version for a schema, by specifying the version in version property of a schemas's property. But there is no version property in a Pipeline's property.

Also, I want to know if we can specify version number for a pipeline component, if yes, then how?

Screenshots attached for better understanding.

[image: Schema Properties Screenshot]

[image: Pipeline Properties Screenshot]

[image: Pipeline Component Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You version Custom Pipeline Components by setting the Assembly Version Number in the Project the component is in.

When you GAC it and add it to your toolbox in Visual Studio, it will read that Assembly Version Number.  So any Pipeline you add it to will be referencing that Version.  There is no need to set it manually.

Comment: Just a quick reminder, you should not put custom Pipeline Components in the %PipelineComponents% folder.  Details: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26404.biztalk-server-deploying-custom-pipeline-components-in-biztalk-server-2006-and-higher.aspx